# heap space issues in hadoop cluster while running map reducer program from command prompt

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop2

I'm running sample map reduce job which takes .csv file as input from hdfs and insert into hbase through java map program. I tried with below options to avoid java heap error.

```
configuration.set("mapreduce.map.java.opts", "-Xmx5g"); 
configuration.set("mapreduce.map.memory.mb", "-1");
```

But I am getting Java Heap issue while running map reduce program.

> 2016-08-30 12:47:26,764 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.skip.on is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.skiprecords
>   2016-08-30 12:50:57,663 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>       at com.google.protobuf.ByteString.copyFrom(ByteString.java:194)
>       at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readBytes(CodedInputStream.java:324)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto$ColumnValue$QualifierValue.(ClientProtos.java:9144)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto$ColumnValue$QualifierValue.(ClientProtos.java:9089)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto$ColumnValue$QualifierValue$1.parsePartialFrom(ClientProtos.java:9198)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$MutationProto$ColumnValue$QualifierValue$1.parsePartialFrom(ClientProtos.java:9193)

```
Driver program configuration as below :
Job job = new Job(configuration);       
job.setJarByClass(HbaseTest.class);     
job.setJobName("Data loading to HBase Table::"+TABLE_NAME);     
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);     
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);     
job.setMapperClass(HbaseTestMapper.class);      
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(job, args[0]);        
FileSystem.getLocal(getConf()).delete(new Path(outputPath), true);      
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));      
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Put.class);
```

I am using hadoop 2.x with three node cluster and each node has 32GB. My input file size is 831MB. Kindly help me what is the issue and how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the configuration like

```
configuration.set("mapreduce.child.java.opts", "-Xmx6553m");
configuration.set("mapreduce.map.memory.mb", "8192");
```